# What explains the output for this C code?

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, character

```
char s[] = "MAC122";
char *p = s;
printf("%s", p + p[2] - p[1]);
```

When I run the C code, the output is "C122", but I don't really understand these + and - operations with the elements of the string and can't find any online references. Could anyone help me?

Comment: The answers provided are mostly correct, but they miss one problem: `p + p[2] - p[1]` is actually Undefined Behaviour. That's because it must be interpreted as `(p + p[2]) - p[1]` (by the rules for grouping expressions, addition associates to the left), and `p + p[2]` is therefore `p + 67`. But the array pointed to by `p` has only 7 elements (including the NUL), and the result of pointer addition must be a pointer within or just after the array pointed into, so you can't add more than 7 to `p`. `p + (p[2] - p[1])` would be fine, since it works out to `p + 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  This is caused by the **type conversion in C**.

### Background: Printing `char*`

Let's start with a simple example:

```
printf("%s", p);
```

This will print all the characters starting from the address `p`, i.e. "MAC122".
That's because the string in the memory looks like

[image: Memory layout]

And `printf` keeps printing characters until it finds '\0', i.e. the terminator.

So what if you do this?

```
printf("%s", p+2);
```

This will print out "C122", which is exactly your case.

That means the `p + p[2] - p[1]` somehow equal to `p+2`, right?  That's because of the algorithmic operations of between types.

### Algorithmic operations between types

First, we know that `p[2]` is exactly the character `C`, and `p[1]` is `A`.

What happens if we do the operation `'C' - 'A'`?  That results in the conversion from the `char` into the ASCII. (It's not really a conversion physically because the computer stores the ASCII value, but logically it helps to understand)  Then `p[2]-p[1]` equal to `'C'-'A'` equal to `67 - 65` equal to `2`.

Similarly, `p + p[2] - p[1]` equal to `p + 67 - 65` equal to `p+2`.  Using the former knowledge of how printf works, this explains why you get the "C122" output.

Comment: ASCII is not an `unsigned short`. `char` is generally just one byte, and may or may not be signed; it happens that ASCII codes are all positive, but they don't really have types. If you mean that the subtraction promotes its arguments to `unsigned short`, that's also wrong: arithemtic operators are promoted to (at least) `int`, and they are promoted to `signed int` if the signed version is wide enough to contain all possible values of the type being converted, which is the case here.

Comment: You're right.  `short` is 2 bytes and `char` is only 1 byte.  In addition, could you elaborate a bit more on "they are promoted to signed int if the signed version is wide enough to contain all possible values of the type being converted"?  Who should be "wide enough" here?

Comment: Also, why are arithmetic operators promoted to at least int?  I thought the compiler is able to issue 8-bit wide arithmetic operations, like `add %al, %al`, right?

Comment: The computer could do it. But C doesn't allow it. And it's the `signed int` which has to be wide enough. If it's not wide enough, the operands will be promoted to `unsigned int`, which is why `signed < unsigned` is considered dangerous. Search for "usual arithmetic conversions" with your favourite search tool.

Comment: Re "*Who should be "wide enough" here?*", `int`. If `int` it not big enough to hold every value of `char`, `unsigned int` will be used instead. So unless you have a really weird system, `p[1] - p[2]` is equivalent to `(int)p[1] - (int)p[2]`. See [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: I see.  That's interesting.

Comment: Re "*You're right. short is 2 bytes*", No. "Byte" is a confusing word. It doesn't necessarily mean 8 bits. I'm going to assume you mean a short is 2 octets, or 16 bits. But that's not correct. A `short` is *at least* 16 bits in size. It's guaranteed to hold -32767..32767 inclusive (but not -32768), but it can also support larger ranges. (It's also guaranteed to be at least as big as a `char`, no matter the number of bits in a `char`). If you want a type that's exactly 16 bits in size, use `int16_t`/`uint16_t`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the explanation.  That makes sense.  Although I am still shocked that a `byte` can be other than 8 bits.

Comment: There was a system where the size of a `char` (which is the definition of a byte) was 32 bits. That's the largest. But a number of other "odd" sizes have been spotted. There are signal processing chips with 9 bit chars. I think 12 has been seen as well, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: What?  What was the name of the system?  I tried to search for systems that have `byte` not equal to 8 bits but couldn't find one.

Comment: Sorry, don't know. /// But oh! There were system with where the smallest type was only 6 bits in size. But C89 and newer (and possibly older versions too) require a `char` to be at least 8 bits in size. (The number of bits is given by `CHAR_BIT`.) /// And the reason -32768 isn't guaranteed is because C supports machines that use one's complement integers, and those that use sign-magnitude integers.

Comment: That's an interesting story to know.  Thanks!

Comment: @ikegami: although support for architectures other than two's-complement will end with C23. (IMO, good news for everyone except pedants :-) )

Comment: @rici, I almost added "That said, I don't see any reason to ever return to one's complement or sign magnitude". So that's great news.

Answer (score 0):

The catch lies here: `p + p[2] - p[1]`. `p[2]` is `'C'`, `p[1]` is `'A'`. In C, all characters are represented by their ASCII values and `'C' - 'A'` happens to be `2` because `'C'` is the second letter after `'A'`. So, now we have `p + 2`.

`p` is a pointer to a `char` and pointer arithmetic dictates that `p` be incremented exactly one byte for each increment. Thus, `p + 2` points to the character `'C'` in the string.

`printf` starts from `'C'` and carries on until it finds a `'\0'` at the end of the string. Which gives you `"C122"`.

Comment: Wow! Now it makes sense why it would have different outputs depending on the initial string. TY so much!

Comment: Please note that `p + p[2] - p[1]`  does not involve a computation of `p[2] - p[1]`. It must be computed as `(p + p[2]) - p[1]`, which is technically Undefined Behaviour because the result of the addition is outside of the array pointed to. (Of course, it will generally work in practice. But you still shouldn't do it; prefer `p + (p[2] - p[1])`.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to understand it:

For `printf("%s", p + p[2] - p[1]);`, The value of `p+p[2]-p[1]` will be calculated.

- `p` <- holds a number that represents a memory address. (`p` is a pointer)
- `p[2]` <- holds a number **67** represent `C`.
- `p[1]` <- holds a number **65** represent `A`.

The expression becomes `p+2`,

`print("%s", p+2)` means print the string starting from the 3rd char.